# Parse String Time to JS Date Obj

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a string of time such as `"7:30am"` to JavaScript Date Object like `Sat Nov 18 2017 7:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

My approach:

```
function dateObj(d) { // date parser ...
  var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
    date  = new Date();
  if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
        return date
}
var startTime = "7:30";
var endTime   = "9:30pm";
var startDate = dateObj(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);
console.log(startDate, endDate)
```

I got Invalid Date for both startDate, endDate.

Try here:

```js
function dateObj(d) { // date parser ...
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date  = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') { 
       parts[0] = parts[0] + 12; 
    }
    date.setHours(parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(parts.shift());
  return date
}
var startTime = "7:30am";
var endTime   = "9:30pm";
var now       = new Date();
var startDate = dateObj(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);
var test = dateObj(startTime)
console.log(startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: How do you derive the specific day for the time? you can use `date.setDay()`, `date.setDate()`, `date.setYear()`, `date.setMonth()` but how do u choose what to do?

Comment: Just get the current day, for everyday. But I need the specific hour and minute.

Comment: oh ok i see now

Comment: try it without the `+` signs...you dont want the numeric representation...u just want what is there.

Comment: I have tried, it still return "Invalid Date"

Comment: hmmmm..well would leave the plus signs out anyway

Comment: oh i see it this line `if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;`....that doesnt make any sense

Comment: ur missing an open bracket

Comment: that code snippet needs the space between time and `am/pm` too.

Comment: Do you want this to be based on a specific timezone? or just the local timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a regular expression to extract the date elements and also add some error handling for the case the date format is not valid.

And do not forget also to handle 12am and 12pm. This needs extra handling in the code.

See below:

```js
function dateObj(d) { // date parser ...
  const rx = /(\d{1,2})\:(\d{1,2})\s*(am|pm)/g;
  const parts = rx.exec(d);
  if (parts === null) {
    return "Not a valid date: " + d;
  }
  date = new Date();
  const amPm = parts.pop().toLowerCase();
  const hour = parseInt(parts[1]);
  if (amPm === 'pm') {
    if (hour !== 12) {
      parts[1] = (parseInt(parts[1])) + 12;
    }
  } else if (amPm === 'am' && hour === 12) {
    parts[1] = 0;
  }
  date.setHours(parts[1]);
  date.setMinutes(parts[2]);
  return date
}

var startTime = "7:30";
var endTime = "9:30pm";
var startDate = dateObj(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate = dateObj(endTime);

console.log(startDate, endDate)
console.log(dateObj("7:30 pm"))
console.log(dateObj("7:30 am"))
console.log(dateObj("7:30am"))
console.log(dateObj("12:30pm"))
console.log(dateObj("12:30 am"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me if you enter `9:30 pm` instead of `9:30pm`, the white space needs to be there for `regex`:

```
function dateObj(d) {
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date = new Date();

    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
        parts[0] = parts[0] + 12;
    }

    date.setHours(parts[0]);
    date.setMinutes(parts[1]);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it on your browser? still give me Invalid Date :(

Comment: you need a space between `9:30` and `pm` for one thing...but still looking

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new Date object that includes the current time.

But it is based on the timezone of where the code is run.

```
var timeRe = /(\d+):(\d+)([amp]*)/gi;
function timeParse(time) {
  var today = new Date();
  var match = time.split(timeRe);
  console.log(time, match);
  if (match) {
    var hours = parseInt(match[1],10)+(match[3].toLowerCase()==='pm'?12:0)%24;
    today.setHours(hours);
    today.setMinutes(parseInt(match[2],10));
    today.setSeconds(0);
  }
  return today;

}
var startTime = "7:30";
var endTime   = "9:30pm";
var startDate = timeParse(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate   = timeParse(endTime);
console.log(startDate, endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a space before am/pm :

```js
d = t => new Date(new Date().toDateString() + t.replace(/(.*\d)/, " $1 "))

console.log(d("7:30").toString())
console.log(d("7:30am").toString())
console.log(d("9:30pm").toString())
```